# To prove $p⊕q$, does it suffice to prove $p\implies \sim q$ and $\sim p\implies q$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

By p⊕q, also written p xor q, I mean *either $p$ or $q$ but not both*; and I use the symbol $\sim $ to negate propositions.

Comment: Either $p$ or $q$ but not both is called exclusive or (xor). To check whether what you are asking is true try making the truth tables for both the expressions and compare them.

Comment: This is known as [Exclusive Or](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) which is sometimes denoted $p \oplus q$

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Just did, mate. Thank you!

Comment: @WaveX didn't know, thank you!

Comment: Did you mean pr**o**positions where you typed prepositions in the title?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Hehehe, yeah.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Out of Giorgos's Advice I made the truth tables for both expressions and realised they're logically equivalent. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since $$((p\to\lnot q)\land(\lnot p\to q))\:\leftrightarrow\:((p\lor q)\land\lnot(p\land q))$$ is a tautology, the assumptions $$(p\implies\lnot q) \text{ and } (\lnot p\implies q)$$ jointly indeed suffice to entail the conclusion $$p ⊕ q.$$